# Exporting the users from a domain local group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Could you please help me with the following code ? 
It works just fine, but I need the `samAccountName` not the `distinguishedName` and it won't work just by replacing `distinguishedName` with `samAccountName`.

**Here it is:**

```
$s = "LDAP://" + (Get-ADGroup "Name of Group").DistinguishedName
([ADSI]$s) | select -ExpandProperty member|
             select @{Name='members';Expression={[string]::j}}
```

Thank you !

Comment: May I ask why are you using `[adsi]` if you have access to the AD PS Module?

Comment: I agree with @Santiago,  you can just use `Get-ADGroupMember` if I remember correctly. ADSI you have to reference the `properties` attribute first, then the `member` property.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get the membership of an AD Group, this should do the trick:

```
(Get-ADGroup 'groupName' -Properties member).member.foreach({
    $_.split(',')[0].replace('CN=','')
})
```

This should return the `samAccountName` of each member, there is no need to use `[adsi]` if you already have the `ActiveDirectory Module`

#### Edit:

So, I was assuming that `samAccountName` and `Name` hold the same value for you, my bad. So this is how you can get what you need using AD module:

```
(Get-ADGroup 'groupName' -Properties member).member.foreach({
    (Get-ADUser $_).samAccountName
})
```

You can also use the cmdlet that was designed exactly for this:

```
(Get-ADGroupMember 'groupName').samAccountName
```

Comment: It works, except now it`s bringing the full name instead of samaccountname (logonname)

Comment: @cpitis I see, so the objects `Name` are not the same as the `samAccountName` on your Domain. I see the point. I'll add a new example showing you how you can do it with an `AD` cmdlet.

Comment: Yes !! This is it ! Thank you a lot, have a great day !

Comment: @cpitis no problem, happy to help.